# XCode ignores target-level preprocessor macro

Tags: xcode, preprocessor

In XCode 4.5, my preprocessor macro gets ignored when defined at target level, but honored if defined at project level. It's a simple symbol definition (RESTKIT_GENERATE_SEED_DB) to be used in #ifdef. Using "levels" display, XCode shows my symbol in the resolved section. Also, I have double-checked that my current scheme is running the Debug config where macro is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a newbie mistake. The setup was that I had two targets, one with the macro defined and one without. The reason the macro was not picked up at target level was that I never ran that target. I thought that you ran it by selecting the target in the target list under TARGETS. I realize now that in order to run a target you must select it the scheme menu next to where you select the device target.